# Where is the default header Cache-Control value from in puma (with rails 5)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, puma

I found my project default Cache-Control setting is `max-age=0, private, must-revalidate` , though I can override it by  `config.action_dispatch.default_headers`.
But I still wonder where the default value orginally set in code or in puma?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I figure it out: https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/master/lib/rack/etag.rb.
If your ror application use Rack::ETag